# Error while returning reference, static reference and value

Tags: rust, reference, static

```rs
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

struct Deploy(PathBuf);

impl Deploy {
    fn values_yaml(self) -> Path {
        let values_yaml = self.0.join("helm").join("chart").join("values.yaml");
        values_yaml
    }
}
```

This is my function,
When the return type is `&Path` I get  `expected named lifetime parameter`.
When the return type is `&static Path` I get returns `a reference to data owned by the current function`.
When the return type `Path` I get  `doesn't have a size known at compile-time`.

How can I make the functionality work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path` is an unsized type, meaning that it must always be used behind a pointer like `&` or `Box`. The owned version of this type is `PathBuf`. `PathBuf` implements `Deref` to `Path`, so you can use all of its methods. This explains why you cannot return `Path`.
Now why can't you return `&Path` from your method? Have a look at `join`: `Creates an owned PathBuf with path adjoined to self`. So you create a new `PathBuf` in your method and return a reference to it. But this new one will be dropped as soon as the method ends and the `PathBuf` goes out of scope. You also currently take ownership of `self`, so this would drop the `PathBuf` even if you do not create a new one but just push to it.

So how would solutions look like? Assuming you do not want to modify the `PathBuf` in `Deploy`, you'd simply return an owned `PathBuf`.

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

struct Deploy(PathBuf);

impl Deploy {
    fn values_yaml(&self) -> PathBuf {
        self.0.join("helm").join("chart").join("values.yaml")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = r"/etc";
    let deploy = Deploy(PathBuf::from(s));
    let values_yaml = deploy.values_yaml();
    i_take_a_path(&values_yaml);
}

fn i_take_a_path(path: &Path) {
    println!("{:?}", path);
}
```

If you really want to modify the underlying `PathBuf` of `Deploy`, you'd go with that:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

struct Deploy(PathBuf);

impl Deploy {
    fn values_yaml(&mut self) -> &Path {
        self.0.push("helm");
        self.0.push("chart");
        self.0.push("values.yaml");
        self.0.as_path()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = r"/etc";
    let mut deploy = Deploy(PathBuf::from(s));
    let values_yaml = deploy.values_yaml();
    i_take_a_path(values_yaml);
}

fn i_take_a_path(path: &Path) {
    println!("{:?}", path);
}
```

This time the reference works, because it is directly pointing to the `PathBuf` in `Deploy`, and not a newly created one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have here is that the `Path` type is a reference type. It basically points to an existing owning `PathBuf`.

It is a relation equivalent to what a `str` is to a `String`.

In addition, the `Path::join()` method returns a `PathBuf` (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join).

The solution here is to change your return type accordingly:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

struct Deploy(PathBuf);

impl Deploy {
    fn values_yaml(self) -> PathBuf {
        let values_yaml = self.0.join("helm").join("chart").join("values.yaml");
        values_yaml
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca3406afa0bd8d93f96423f7211b3f9d)